# Push notifications (Parse/Cloud Code) not showing username for comments, or any likes

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios8, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse and Cloud Code for the first time to update a photo-sharing app that was built with Parse and Objective-C for iOS 8. I've followed Parse's instructions for setting up push notifications and was successfully able to receive a notification when a photo was commented on, but it is only delivering the "else" statement that says "*Someone* has commented on your photo" (instead of giving user's name). Aside from that, 'like' notifications aren't being pushed at all.

Here's my cloud code (JavaScript) that I modeled after Parse's AnyPic tutorial. I also have an installation file and a "main" file that point to this one and the installation. What am I missing here?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Activity', function(request, response) {
  var currentUser = request.user;
  var objectUser = request.object.get('fromUser');

  if(!currentUser || !objectUser) {
    response.error('An Activity should have a valid fromUser.');
  } else if (currentUser.id === objectUser.id) {
    response.success();
  } else {
    response.error('Cannot set fromUser on Activity to a user other than the current user.');
  }
});

Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Activity', function(request) {
  // Only sends push notifications for new activities.
  if (request.object.existed()) {
    return;
  }

  var toUser = request.object.get("toUser");
  if (!toUser) {
    throw "Undefined toUser. Skipping push for Activity " + request.object.get('type') + " : " + request.object.id;
    return;
  }

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo('user', toUser);

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query.
    data: alertPayload(request)
  }).then(function() {
    // Push was successful
    console.log('Sent push.');
  }, function(error) {
    throw "Push Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
  });
});

var alertMessage = function(request) {
  var message = "";

  if (request.object.get("type") === "comment") {
    if (request.user.get('displayName')) {
      message = request.user.get('displayName') + ': ' + request.object.get('content').trim();
    } else {
      message = "Someone left a comment on your photo.";
    }
  } else if (request.object.get("type") === "like") {
    if (request.user.get('displayName')) {
      message = request.user.get('displayName') + ' likes your photo.';
    } else {
      message = 'Someone likes your photo.';
    }
  }

  // Trim our message to 140 characters.
  if (message.length > 140) {
    message = message.substring(0, 140);
  }

  return message;
}

var alertPayload = function(request) {
  var payload = {};

  if (request.object.get("type") === "comment") {
    return {
      alert: alertMessage(request), // Sets the alert message.
      badge: 'Increment', // Increments the target device's badge count.
      // The following keys help Cosplace to load the photo corresponding to this push notification.
      p: 'a', // Payload Type: Activity
      t: 'c', // Activity Type: Comment
      fu: request.object.get('fromUser').id, // From User
      pid: request.object.id // Photo Id
    };
  } else if (request.object.get("type") === "like") {
    return {
      alert: alertMessage(request), // Sets the alert message.
      // The following keys help Cosplace to load the photo corresponding to this push notification.
      p: 'a', // Payload Type: Activity
      t: 'l', // Activity Type: Like
      fu: request.object.get('fromUser').id, // From User
      pid: request.object.id // Photo Id
    };
  }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the Objective-C code from my AppDelagate.m file (I took out the Parse IDs):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [Parse setApplicationId: @""

                      clientKey:@""];

        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

        // Reset application icon badge number when app is launched.
        if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
        }

        // Registers the current device for push notifications.
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

        if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced
            // in iOS 7). In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double
            // counting the app-open.
            BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
            BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
            BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
            }
        }
        // If the registration is successful, this callback method will be executed. This method informs Parse about this new device.
        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
            // Reset application icon badge number when app is launched.
            if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0) {
                application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

            // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
            PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        //    [PFInstallation.currentInstallation setObject:PFUser.currentUser forKey:@"user"];
            [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
            // Associate the device with a user
            PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
            installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
            [installation saveInBackground];
            [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

            // Create Parse Installation query
            PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
            [pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

            }
        }
            // So when logged out notifications stop being received.
        - (void)logOut {
            // Unsubscribe from push notifications by removing the user association from the current installation.
            [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] removeObjectForKey:@"user"];
            [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
        }

        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
            [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AppDelegateApplicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
        }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

        // Clear badge and update installation for auto-incrementing badges.
        if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber != 0) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
        }
}
```

Comment: It's possible you dont get the full user object through `request.user`. You may have to query for the full users details before sending the push.

Comment: Hm. Thanks I'll have to look i to how to do that. I thought that's what I was already doing.

Comment: So I realized the JavaScript for the Parse Cloud Code probably needs to refer to [this Parse table](http://i.imgur.com/inUDbV7.png?1). That's where the Parse classes are set up for recording comments on photos. "fromUserName" is the username of the person placing the comment, & "fromUser" is their user ID (the pointer). I thought request.user.get() should call "fromUser" to get the user ID before calling "fromUserName" in the push message, but that didn't change anything. Since I'm getting the "else" message for comments, it must be 'if (request.user.get('fromUser'))' that's not right.

Comment: I figured it out. Where I have "displayName" I needed to use "fromUser", from my Parse class table. I also needed to change the message to use "request.object.get(fromUserName)" instead of "request.user.get(displayName)."